# DiDOM : How to unwrap a parent node and elevate the children?

Tags: php, html, dom

I have a question about the [DiDOM](https://github.com/Imangazaliev/DiDOM) HTML/XML DOM parsing package.

I have the following sample HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
        <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>4</p>
        <p>5</p>
        <p>6</p>
        <div>
            <p>7</p>
            <p>8</p>
            <p>9</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

What I want to do is "unwrap" each `<div>` by relocating the `<p>` child nodes to be direct descendants of the div's parent, and deleting the now-empty `<div>` node. I tried doing it using the code below, but it only works on some nodes; on others, the `$tag` element has no parent and therefore you can't use `insertSiblingBefore(...)` without throwing an exception.

Here's some sample code to call the the desired function:

```
// Remove <div> tags with no attributes
$divTags = $doc->find( 'div' );
foreach ( $divTags as $divTag ) {
    removeElementKeepingChildren( $divTag );
}
```

...and here's the offending code itself:

```
function removeElementKeepingChildren( Element $tag ) : void {
    // I'd like to avoid needing this check...but without it, certain $tags cause the exception
    if ( ! $tag->parent() ) {
        return;
    }

    // "Backup" the children
    $children = $tag->children();

    // Remove the children from the node to be removed
    $tag->removeChildren();

    foreach ( $children as $child ) {
        $tag->insertSiblingBefore( $child );
    }

    $tag->remove();
}
```

There's got to be a better way to do this...suggestions?

Comment: Every node in a DOM tree that is not the root node, _must_ have a parent. If you encounter div nodes there that don't have one - then the only logical explanation would be, that this node somehow has already been removed from the document. I don't know how the find method of that library works, if the result has "live" properties same as you would have with a live HTMLCollection that you get from a method like getElementsByTagName in JavaScript. [...]

Comment: [...] If(!) that was the case, then looping over nodes while removing some of them, can easily get problematic. In such cases I usually find it best to iterate them in reverse order, using a `for` loop - then you can remove any nodes you encounter as you like.